# Leveling system DiscordJS, Not sending data to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js

Im creating a simple leveling system that sends the data through mongoDB but the bot runs it just isnt sending the data? and it doesnt even really seem to ever end up calling the xpGiver function which in theory should be called when a new message is sent

I know there a rules or whatever like stuff about "minimal producible example" but Stack overflow seems to struggle with try catch blocks and It wont let me paste my code without making the formatting incorrect.
The xpGiver and its console logs are the big focus.

```
async function xpGiver(message) {
  //console.log('xpGiver function called');
  if (!message.guild || message.author.bot) { // If the message in the guild doesnt exist or if its the bot 
    //console.log('Exiting xpGiver: not applicable message');
    return;
  }
  
  //console.log('Processing xpGiver: applicable message');

  const xpToGive = getRandomXp(5, 15); // 5 or 15
  const query = {
    userId: message.author.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
  };

  try {
    const level = await Level.findOne(query);

    if (level) 
    {
      level.xp += xpToGive;

      if (level.xp > calculateXp(level.level)) 
      {
        level.xp = 0;
        level.level += 1;

        message.channel.send(`${message.member} you have leveled up to level: ${level.level}`);
      }

      await level.save();
    } 
    else 
    {
      const newLevel = new Level({
        userId: message.author.id,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        xp: xpToGive,
      });

      await newLevel.save();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

it doesnt seem to print them which means its not calling here:

```
if (interaction.isMessageComponent()) {
      // Call the xpGiver function with the interaction's message
      await xpGiver(interaction.message);
    }
```

The data is also not getting sent to mongoDB but that shouldn't be surprising since its not even calling the function I think.

```
(async () => {
  try 
  {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {keepAlive: true});
    console.log("connected to db")


    client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
  } catch (e) 
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
  
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  // CREATES THE LEVEL SCHEMA PER THE USER (if exists adds XP)
   xpGiver(message);
});
```

Create a seperate client.on and call the function there